# lines+=line/ TypeError: can't concat str to bytes

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I need to pass the arduino data that is saved on a microSD to the sqlite database of my GUI. Anyone besides being able to fix this error, could you help me pass the data to the database?

```
lines=b''

with serial.Serial('COM5',9600,timeout=2) as ser:
    line = ser.readline()
    line = line.decode("utf-8")
    lines+=line
```

Comment: You need to post a separate question for the database issue. Ideally one question should address one problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have posted above does not match the error. It should be

`lines += line` and not `lines += lines`

`line` in your code is a `str` object and `lines` is defined as `byte`.

So you can do this instead:
`lines += bytes(line, 'utf-8')` to get rid of the error.

Or you could just not call the `decode` on line and keep it as bytes.

Comment: All right, it worked. Would not you know how to pass the arduino microSD data to the graph interface database?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with what you mean by graph interface db. If you post some details about that in another question may be I can help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using Python 3 (it's good practice to specify this information in your question).

Also, I assume that `lines+=lines` is a typo introduced when writing the question and your program uses `lines+=line`.

The pySerial docs for [`read()`](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html?highlight=encode#serial.Serial.read) say it returns bytes, so it's likely that `readline()` also returns bytes.  When you do `line.decode("utf-8")`, you are using the byte string you got from the device to create text string.  Then you are trying to append `line` (type `str`) to `lines` (type `bytes`, because you created it with the bytestring literal `b''`), and that causes the error.

You should be able to solve this either by:

1. creating `lines` as a text string (`lines = ''`)
2. not decoding `line` before appending it to `lines`

Which one you choose probably depends on whether the information provided by the device is actually textual and guaranteed not to fail at the decoding step, or whether it's actually binary and will need to be parsed later in the program.